# Inherit a property in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I'm using Delphi XE3, and I need to override a property in a such way, that I still call base class getter and a new class setter.

Example:

```
TBaseClass = class
  ...
  property XML:string read GetXML write SetXML;
end ;

TNewClass = class(TBaseClass)
  ...
  property: XML .....
end;
```

UPDATE:

The BaseClass is in a .dcu compiled file, so I can't directly change this file.

Comment: Declare SetXML virtual in TBaseClass and override it in TNewClass.

Comment: why does this question got protected? from the answers I do not see any reason for doing this

Comment: @RBA: This question is protected because of spam messages. Someone has recently been posting nasty things towards one particular SO member, and this discussion had received some of those messages, which have been deleted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My problem was solved with this approach:

in TNewClass:

```
private
  function GetXML: string;
  procedure SetXML(const Value: string);

public
  property XML: string read GetXML write SetXML;

procedure TNewClass.SetXML(const Value: string);
begin
  do my job..
end;


function TNewClass.GetXML: string;
begin
  //here call the base GetXML      
  result := Inherited XML;//result := string(Inherited XML);
end;
```

Comment: You don't need the typecast in the getter: `result := inherited XML;`

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted. It is actually the correct answer, considering the fact that the base class code is not accessible for changing the property's getter/setter methods to virtual (which would be the *ideal* solution). The derived class can re-declare the property to use new getter/setter methods that call the base class methods when needed. Even RTL/VCL classes do exactly that.

Comment: @MatheusFreitas: you cannot `reintroduce` a property, and you do not need to `reintroduce` property getter/setter methods if you simply give them unique names that do not conflict with the base class.